# SKScene didMove(to view: SKView) is called twice on some devices (not in simulators and other devices)

Tags: sprite-kit, skview

I've asked this question before (to no avail), and it follows up a more [recent inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69675768/phantom-button-in-spritekit-scene) about the same app.

I have a GameScene called from the body of a SwiftUI view. App deployment is set to iOS 14.0.
On xCode simulators and an iPhone13 (all using iOS 15), the app works as designed.
However, on an iPhone8 using iOS 14.8, it does not work: Print statements to the console indicate that didMove(toView: SKView) is inexplicably being called twice: once when expected and then after the a startGameAction() function is called. The game flashes on the screen for a moment, but then (as didMove() gets called a second time, the view changes to the initial state. But the game is "running" in the background; the music is playing and when the timer runs out, the "Round Over" info is displayed normally.
If it helps, I uploaded [the project to github](https://github.com/hyoryusha/NyonindoChallenge) if any kind and curious person would like to take a look.
Thanks!

Comment: An update: after much more testing, I can say with greater certainty that this is an iOS version problem. In short, an SKView that gets "moved to" only once (as it should) in iOS 15 is moved to twice in iOS 14.

Comment: Hey I found your question on https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/how-can-i-prevent-didmove-to-view-skview-from-firing-twice-when-scene-is-called-by-spriteview/10336. Try changing `Text(viewModel.gameActive ? "Round \(viewModel.attempts + 1) of 3" : "")` to `Text(viewModel.gameActive ? "Round \(viewModel.attempts + 1) of 3" : "Game inactive")`, it might fix the issue. If it doesn't please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your help. As it turns out, i completely reworked the GameScene, so the issue was resolved in a different way. I should have updated my post to reflect that. All the same, thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts.